# Remove underscore with number from string in r

Tags: r, regex

Is there any simple way how to remove underscore before number which has 8 digits everytime?

e.g.

```
test_folder_20180409 should be test_folder
```

or

```
test_sql.sql_20180409 should be test_sql.sql
```

Thanks for any of hint in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `sub`

```
sub("_\\d{8}.*", "", str1)
#[1] "test_folder"  "test_sql.sql"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("test_folder_20180409", "test_sql.sql_20180409")
```

Comment: That was very fast :-) Thank you very much!